# Abrir um modal com um botão noutro modal?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, modal

Eu tenho um modal do `bootstrap` onde tem um botão que fecha o `modal` mas queria que mal fechasse o modal, abrisse outro. Já tentei meter um `id` no botão para ao clickar abrir o modal de novo mas não está funcionando.

Este é o que tenho

```
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top:0;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="open">Inscrever-me nesta aula!</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fullCalModal2" class="modal fade">
    //Texto complementar com divs
</div>
```

Para abrir o primeiro modal, eu abro carregando num `event` do `FullCalendar`, e o outro externamente.

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $("#fullCalModal2").modal();
});
```

Comment: Por que você não ele abrir o outro modal ao clicar no fechar?

Comment: Esse calendar tem o botão fechar com id ou class?

Comment: @adventistaam O que supostamente abre outro modal é só se o utilizador se quiser inscrever e o outro é apenas para fechar o modal

Comment: @adventistaam No fullCalendar, está assim ` $('#fullCalModal').modal();`

Comment: @adventistaam Peço desculpa o código postado estava desatualizado, veja agora

Comment: no `fullCalModal2` tem os botoes identificados? ID ou Class?

Comment: @adventistaam Você tem razão, foi apenas um erro. Existiam dois botões com o mesmo id e eu estive sempre a alterar o botão errado. Publique a sua resposta que você está correto.

Comment: @I_like_trains é para abrir o segundo modal a partir do evento click de algum botão, ou após fechar o primeiro abre o segundo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifique se no `fullCalModal2` tem os botoes identificados? ID ou Class?

Dá uma olhada nesse exemplo:

```js
$('.btn-info').on('click', function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});

$('.btn-botao').on('click', function(){
  $('#myModal1').modal('show');
});
```

```css
#myModal:nth-of-type(even) {
    z-index: 1042 !important;
}
#myModal-backdrop.in:nth-of-type(even) {
    z-index: 1041 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" >Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Principal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-botao">Abri outro Modal</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Secundário</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal secundario.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Você pode ver outro exemplo [aqui](https://www.codeply.com/go/DrHSdcgojX)

Comment: Eu não sabia que era assim... legal.

Comment: Assim como? rs.

Comment: é para abrir o segundo modal logo em cima? a partir do evento do botão? é isso !!!

Comment: Bom eu entendi isso rs

Comment: @VirgilioNovic A sua imagem foi a minha reação ao ver o que tinha de errado

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu entendi, se abre um modal, e logo após o seu fechamento, abre outro modal, se for isso, resolvi fazer um exemplo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#open").click(function() {
    $("#fullCalModal").modal();
  });
  $("#btnopen").on('click', function (e) {
    $("#fullCalModal2").modal();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top:0;">
        <button type="button" id="btnopen" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Inscrever-me nesta aula!</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="fullCalModal2" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top:0;">       
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" id="open">Abrir Modal</button>
```